# Set Excel table filter criteria based on other table filter criteria

Tags: excel, vba, criteria, autofilter

I have multiple tables with a unique ID. Let's say this ID is in column A.

Table 1 is my master table. When I select a value from the table filter for column A, I want to adjust the same criteria to other tables (with VBA code).

With which statement can I read the criteria of table1 filter into a variable, which I can use for the other tables filter criteria?

I can find how to set the AutoFilter on a table with a variable, but I cannot find how to read an active AutoFilter criteria into a variable.

Comment: https://www.get-digital-help.com/copy-excel-table-filter-criteria-vba/

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub simple_example_set_filter(ByVal afilter As String)
   With Range("CC_FILTER_AREA")
      .AutoFilter Field:=1, VisibleDropDown:=False
      .AutoFilter Field:=2, VisibleDropDown:=False
      .AutoFilter Field:=3, VisibleDropDown:=False
      .AutoFilter Field:=4, VisibleDropDown:=False
      .AutoFilter Field:=5, VisibleDropDown:=False
      .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=afilter, Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=~", VisibleDropDown:=False
   End With
End Sub
```

whith this i read some filter and create a string for use in a report:

```
Public Function GetFilterCriteria(rng As Range, Optional prompt As String = vbNullString) As String
Dim str1 As String, str2 As String, c As Long
With rng.Parent.AutoFilter
   c = .Range.Column
   With .Filters(rng.Column - c + 1)
      If Not .On Then
          GetFilterCriteria = vbNullString
          Exit Function
      End If
      str1 = .Criteria1
      If .Operator = xlAnd Then
          str2 = " and " & Mid(.Criteria2, 2)
      ElseIf .Operator = xlOr Then
          str2 = " or " & Mid(.Criteria2, 2)
      End If
   End With
End With
If (Left(str1, 2) = "<>") Then
   GetFilterCriteria = prompt & Mid(str1, 3)
Else
   GetFilterCriteria = prompt & Mid(str1, 2)
End If
'AutoFilter_Criteria = UCase(Rng) & ": " & str1 & str2
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This code is an example for setting a filter. I need to know how I can read an active filter on a table and put the Criteria from that Filter into an variable, which then I can use (with your code) into another filter.

Answer (score 0):

to get the criteria of a filtered table

```
Sub GetCriteria()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim tbl1 As ListObject

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Set tbl1 = ws.ListObjects("Table1")
   
   With tbl1.AutoFilter
      For i = 1 To .Filters.Count
         If .Filters(i).On Then
            '.Range(1, i).Column is the filtered column
            Debug.Print Mid(.Filters(.Range(1, i).Column).Criteria1, 2)
         End If
      Next i
   End With
End Sub
```